# Insert into a particular column in Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a column in my table with the name  7:25_8:30 and this is my SQL statement into Mysql table.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO timetable (7:25_8:30) VALUES('47')");
```

And am getting this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '7:25_8:30) VALUES('47')' at line 1.

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO timetable (7:25_8:30) VALUES(47)"); Int (47)  must not be in ' ' though if it is not a String

Comment: Change your query with this INSERT INTO timetable (` 7:25_8:30 `) VALUES('47'). Write your column in between Back quote.

Answer (score 1):

Use `backticks`

```
INSERT INTO timetable (`7:25_8:30`) VALUES('47');
```